# Error: Floating Point exception in OpenCV, SVM train

Tags: opencv, svm, opencv3.0

I am trying to train svm using descriptor values of HOG feature extractor.

```
//pRow, nRow, pCol, nCol are positive and negative columns and rows.
Mat posneg_descriptor_mat( pRow + nRow, pCol, CV_32FC1 );

// data is descriptor values
memcpy(posneg_descriptor_mat.data, pMat.data, sizeof(float) * pMat.cols * pMat.rows );
int startP = sizeof(float) * pMat.cols * pMat.rows;
memcpy(&(posneg_descriptor_mat.data[ startP ]), nMat.data, sizeof(float) * nMat.cols * nMat.rows );
//data labeling
Mat labels( pRow + nRow, 1, CV_32FC1, Scalar(-1.0) );
    labels.rowRange( 0, pRow ) = Scalar( 1.0 );


Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 10000, 1e-6));

Ptr<TrainData> td =TrainData::create(posneg_descriptor_mat, ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
```

When code is in the line below the error (Floating point exception (core dumped)) occurs:

```
svm->trainAuto(td);
```

Comment: Is this right? svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 10000, 1e-6));

Comment: Probably not directly related to the issue, but you should really avoid `memcpy`. Use `Mat` constructors properly insted, is less error prone. @jas- yes, formally correct. But I don't see where `PN_Descriptor_mtx` is defined

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update name of variable in this place. updated now.

Comment: Can you run in debug and get the error message?

Comment: yes, error  message is :

`Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00007ffff7b94cfd in cv::ml::SVMImpl::trainAuto(cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> const&, int, cv::ml::ParamGrid, cv::ml::ParamGrid, cv::ml::ParamGrid, cv::ml::ParamGrid, cv::ml::ParamGrid, cv::ml::ParamGrid, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0
Single stepping until exit from function _ZN2cv2ml7SVMImpl9trainAutoERKNS_3PtrINS0_9TrainDataEEEiNS0_9ParamGridES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_b,
which has no line number information.`
    
`Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
The program no longer exists.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `CV_32FC1` to `CV_32SC1` solved the problem. Seems like `response` cannot be `float`.